# Why can't you see air but can feel it

Tags: molecules

Is there a device that can measure the air in the room in lbs?

I would appreciate the anseer

Answer (score 2):

A scale.  Consider an experiment where a container of "air" is submerged into liquid helium (just about the coldest stuff known.)  This will turn the air into solid $\ce{N2}$ and solid $\ce{O2}$ which can then be weighed.

If you knew the area of the room, then you would know the "pounds per square inch" or "p.s.i."

But the above answer, I think, is a little cheeky.  I think it is usually done via the ideal gas law:  $ P V = n R T$, and solving for $n$, the number of moles of gas. Then through Avogadro's number, one can deduce the number of molecules.  The molecules (e.g. $\ce{N2}$) have a known molecular weight, which can be expressed in pounds.

A barometer, a thermometer, and a ruler are the only three devices one would need to get the number of pounds of air.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Please, though, consider flagging such "nonsense" (or nearly so) questions for closure.